# How to access the properties of a file upload button?

Tags: css, button, input

can you show me how to assign css properties to the button that is of type=file,say:

```
<input type="file"  name="coolFile">
```

I know that in css you need to do this:

```
  input[type=file]{
     background:#ccf;
//and so on
}
```

How do I assign values for the button?

Comment: You've basically answered your own question. That is exactly how you would assign CSS properties. Am I missing something?

Comment: Seems like you already know the CSS selector. What do you mean by assign values for the button? CSS is only for styling. You can't change the button text using CSS. You need JavaScript for that.

Comment: Ah, i see. It couldn't be done using css. I want to change the border and background of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, mainstream browsers do not allow designers to directly style file input fields. You can consider this a "security feature" because users could potentially be tricked into uploading files if the file input field is styled in a tricky way.

There is a solution that involves creating a second input field, and hiding the actual file input behind it. The following was lifted from http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html:

```
div.fileinputs {
    position: relative;
}

div.fakefile {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}

input.file {
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    -moz-opacity:0 ;
    filter:alpha(opacity: 0);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

<div class="fileinputs">
    <input type="file" class="file" />
    <div class="fakefile">
        <input />
        <img src="search.gif" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw this solution but I think I will leave the buttons as they are.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to change the button's text, here's one tutorial on how to do that:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

If it's just the plain CSS properties like colour/border/etc, you already have the answer, you just need to check stuff to find out why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You use [DOM/JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/HTMLDOM/dom_obj_style.asp), e.g:

```
document.getElementById("id").style.property="value"
```