# How can I upload a new file on click of image button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got a task to upload new file from the click of image button.
My code is

```
    <label>File</lable>
    <input type="image" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Button-Lightblue.svg" width="30px"/>
```

On the click of this button I want to upload a new file.How can I do this?
You can check my code from
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bkzfk/)

Comment: Your closing label tag is misspelled. To upload an image you really need the 'file' input type. Info here on styling etc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909228/style-input-type-file

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You could add a hidden file input field, like:

```
<input type="image" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Button-Lightblue.svg" width="30px"/>
<input type="file" id="my_file" style="display: none;" />
```

And do:

```
$("input[type='image']").click(function() {
    $("input[id='my_file']").click();
});
```

Demo:: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bkzfk/1/)

Comment: @Sudhir-How can I print the name in the html

Comment: @DemoUser, this is not working for me(javascript). no action taking place

Comment: well it works fine for me, do you get any js error..?

Comment: @Vijay Kumar: you must use document ready and place the code inside it

Answer (score 17):

There is no need for javascript just put the `<input>` and the `<img>` inside `<label>` make sure you hide the `<input>` like so:

```html
<label for="image">
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" style="display:none;"/>
    <img src="IMAGE URL"/>
</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for javascript.

```
Just place both <input type="file"> and <img src=""> inside a label.

Eg:
<label>
    <input type="file" style="display:none">
<img src=""> 
</label>
```

This will work Just Fine

Demo: https://codepen.io/sandeeprana1001/pen/dyPVvJZ

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a cross-browser compatible solution you should check out plupload(http://www.plupload.com) it supports image buttons aswell from what i remember.

Answer (score 2):

you are using the wrong input, use file instead, if you want the button to loke like the circle in your code demo you will need to use CSS to change the way "submit" looks like. This has to be in a form:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="myfile"/>
  <input type="submit" class="circle-btn"/>
<form>
```

I don't know what language are you using in the server-side (PHP, ASP.NET, etc) but you will need to create a page (for xample "upload_file.php" for php). You can easily find examples in google about how to create a page like that, just copy pasete the code:

An example in PHP: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using css.

Please check the 4th answer in this blog.

> [How can I customize the browse button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519223/how-can-i-customize-the-browse-button)

You can use your image as background image of the **.button** class.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this in order to access the file that you uploaded since in PHP you can't access the file inside a label.

```
<input type="file" name="input" id="input" style="display:none;">
<label for="input">
    <img src="images/default.jpg" id="image">
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Supplement for DemoUser's answer, add .focus() works for me.

```
  $("input[type='image']").click(function() {
    $("input[id='my_file']").focus().click();
  });
```