# Custom <input type="file"> not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use a custom < input type="file" > button. This works in chrome and FF. How do I make it work in IE 10 and above?

**The problem in IE is that the browse box is not opening.**

html:

```
<button type="button" id="fileT"><input type="file" id="file"></button>
```

css:

```
#fileT{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#fileT input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.1
}
```

Comment: What is not working...

Comment: the Browse box is not showing.

Comment: which version of IE..please include in question..

Comment: I'm using IE version 10. I just updated my post. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got what you mean: since `<input type="file"/>` is hard to style, you need a container. 
Then try using a `<div>` instead of a `<button>`.

Just ensure you specify height and width since the div content will be absolutely positioned (and hence stripped from the flow).

[Running demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n9u2k2pp/):

```
<div id="fileT">
    <input type="file" id="file" />
</div>

#fileT{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 75px;
    height: 50px;
}
#fileT input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Why <DIV> and not <BUTTON>? Are you using the DIV as a mask?

Comment: [`<button>`s suck with (old ?) IE](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/button-tag-in-IE). Also read [when to use a `<button>`](http://css-tricks.com/use-button-element/), and [`<button>` vs `<input type="button" />`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/469084/1654265)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove that button and try with just input tag.. It works..

Like this

```
<input type="file" id="file" value="Browse"/>
```

if you want to have your custom button then you have to remove `position:absolute` and keep `opacity:0`

Comment: Thanks, but the `< button >` tags are important as I'm trying to create a customised button.

Comment: Bro.. I think that might be an IE problem.. Might b u have to follow different approach..

Comment: As 'V2Solutions''s answer there seems to be a bug in IE. Any suggestions other suggestons to have a custom browse button?

Comment: @Fergoso.. This link might help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519223/how-can-i-customize-the-browse-button


+ this too...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842274/cross-browser-custom-styling-for-file-upload-button


and 


http://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/fEdrz

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach is wrong. The input field `<input type="file">` should not include inside the `<button>`.

This will work.

```
<input type="file" id="file">
```

Comment: Thanks. That sure works but I need a custom styled button instead of the standard one.

Comment: Okay.. Anyway you got answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:-

```
<input type="file" id="file" multiple="true"/>
    <button type="button" id="fileT">Upload</button>
```

**OR**

It might be version problem.

**Updated1:-**

This is bug from IE 10 Desktop.To be more specific here's the IE 10 Desktop version:

```
Version: 10.0.9200.16540
Update Versions: 10.0.4 (KB2817183) 
Product ID: 00150-20000-00003-AA459
```

[Refer This](http://forums.asp.net/t/1899623.aspx?Upload%20file%20using%20HTML5%20FormData%20not%20working%20for%20IE10%20Desktop)

**Updated2:-**
Html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="button">Upload</div>
    <input type="file" id="file" multiple="true"/>
</div>
<div id="notice">Nothing to upload</div>
```

Css:

```
#button
{
   
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #0f0;
}

#wrapper
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/HJGFh/95/)

Comment: you are using IE 10 Desktop or Metro?

Comment: Thanks for the info. YOur suggestion did not work. Does this mean that a custom button is not allowed in IE10+?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to surround the input tags with button tags, as the input for file upload automatically creates a browse button for you. When you click it in IE you are just clicking the empty button and not the browse one created by the input which is why it is not doing anything.
So instead of:

```
<button type="button" id="fileT"><input type="file" id="file"></button>
```

Replace simply with:

```
<input type="file" id="fileT">
```

Comment: Thanks. My requirement is a custom styled button instead of the standard one. Example: my above code in chrome.

Comment: Well in that case I suggest you style the input tag using CSS rather than a button, as this is not really meant to be used like this, in essence you are using a button as the background for another button.

Comment: Yes I have to avoid buttons here, I think that's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = document.getElementById('Selectfile');
if (!input) {
    input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'file';
    input.id = "Selectfile";
    document.body.appendChild(input);
}
input.onchange = function (e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0]; 
};
input.click();
```