# Select folder path in ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, directory

I want to choose folder and get path of this folder to save file.
But I can not select folder in ASP.NET web application.
I tried some code bellow:

```
<input id="input-folder-1" type="file" webkitdirectory />
```

But It just active in Chorme, not in IE and I need it in IE
Anyone can help me?
Thank you

Comment: Do you have a `button` or `div` element that wraps this file input?

Comment: @SelimYildiz No. I do not. I just need a button to select folder and get path from this folder

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991907/custom-input-type-file-not-working-in-ie it may help